# (ODOO 11) Llamar a una vista formulario con un método a través de un botón

Tags: odoo

No consigo que me devuelva el formulario del autor. Me lo devuelve vacío por tanto, sospecho que es un asunto de id.

Este es mi metodo:

```
def action_library_book_information_author(self):
    return {
        "name": "Author Information",
        "view_type": "form",
        "view_mode": "form",
        "res_model": "library.author",
        "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "red_id": self.id
    }
éste es mi xml:
<button type="object" name="action_library_book_information_author" string="Author Information"
      class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

Y el módelo al que llamo con  `author = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='library.author', string='Author')` 
es éste:

```
class LibraryAuthor(models.Model):
    _name = 'library.author'

    name = fields.Char('Author: ')
    active = fields.Boolean(default=True)
    country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country')
    # country_image = fields.Binary(related='country_id.image')  intento para coger un único campo de otro modelo.

    book_ids = fields.Many2many('library.book', string="Books")
    book_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='library.book', string="Books")
```

De paso si me podéis explicar la diferencia entre usar una view-action, o un método lo agradecería. No llego a entender la lógica del uso de las vistas: ir.actions.act_window".

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Un error sintáctico ha sido el problema 'red es 'res'. Por otro lado el acceso a la id es así:
Solución:
"res_id": self.author.id,